# Will there be a functional language which does for the Java community what F# does for the .NET community?

Tags: functional-programming, jvm

Will there be a functional language which does for the Java community what F# does for the .NET community?

What functional programming languages are available, or in development, for the JVM?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps [Clojure](http://clojure.org/). It's not statically typed, but it has more of an emphasis on immutability and concurrency than F#. However, like F# (and unlike Common Lisp), it is intended to be a primarily functional language that is good at consuming OO libraries from the underlying platform.

Comment: +1 'cause its right, and it puts you at 10 which gives jop his Populist badge

Comment: I wish Lisp syntax was more likable;-)

Comment: Same here. Oh if only enjoyed seeing a sea of parens and the constant bottom up mental parsing you have to do because of incessant prefix notation... I would use Lisp. I think I'm the only person that thinks ML languages are syntactically beautiful.

Answer (score 44):

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) would be the language.

Though not strictly functional (it's a mix of functional and object-oriented) and it is not strictly for Java (there is a [.NET version of Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/168)), that would be the closest analog to F# in the JVM.

Comment: F# is not strictly functional either - you can program using OO/procedural if you like too :-)

Comment: Scala:functional::C++:object-oriented

Comment: Congratulations on your Populist badge

Answer (score 20):

The first thing that came to my mind was **Scala** but really **[Ocaml-Java](http://ocamljava.x9c.fr/)** comes closer as F# is a variant of Ocaml. See [this post that compares Ocaml-Java to Scala](http://groups.google.com/group/jvm-languages/msg/b7edd5f9e6ed0361?pli=1):

> OCaml programmers are typically over 10x as productive as Java or C++ 
>   programmers for a wide range of practical tasks. Despite being based upon a 
>   fundamentally OOP platform, F# goes a long way to capturing the productivity- 
>   boosting benefits of OCaml (and the whole ML family). In contrast, Scala 
>   fails to capture many of the benefits including some really basic ones and, 
>   consequently, writing correct code is much more difficult in Scala than in 
>   any real ML.
>
> Moreover, the ML family of languages are designed to be succinct but Scala is 
>   needlessly verbose for everything from "Hello world!" upwards. The ML family 
>   of languages provide extensive type inference (OCaml more than most) but 
>   Scala has only rudimentary inference by comparison. OCaml has an unusually 
>   expressive type system but Scala adds little to OOP that is of practical 
>   importance.

Comment: While there is no argument that ML/OCaml is a lot more concise and functional than Scala, it is hard to support all of the claims in the (somewhat dated) forum post.  I do agree though that Scala does not fit the analogy.  F# is basically OCaml for the CLR.

Comment: @Daniel: I'd have to agree fully. There are a few scenarios where F#/OCaml offer this advantage, but for most day-to-day programming (i.e. most people's bread and butter) this claim is simply unrealistic.

Comment: The author of the linked post (Jon Harrop) commonly trolls usenet and other fora to drum up consulting business. Take his advice with a grain of salt--he's trying to sell you something.

Comment: The post doesn't really give any kind of advice--just some select examples that compare OCaml to Scala. Regardless of who the author is the examples are valid and illustrative unless he's making a straw man argument by giving poor Scala examples.

Comment: Nathan, you're saying that I am not trustworthy because my money is literally on OCaml and F# and not on Scala. That does not make sense to me but I suppose you expect me to value your opinion as a student who has not contributed to any of these language communities?

Comment: I don't happen to be a big fan of Jon, but as a full time Haskell programmer (who switched from Java and Ruby by choice), I agree with the criticisms he makes in that Usenet post, and the type of features he describes are something I constantly rely on in day-to-day programming.

Comment: @Curt: So *you're* the Haskell programmer who gives a shit? ;-) http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2010/12/haskell-researchers-announce-discovery.html

Answer (score 3):

For now I would say Scala. But for the future, I'd have a look at Fortress. The first implementation of the spec was released on April 1, 2008. And no, that is not a joke. Key featues are:

- Statically typed, but a lot of type inference to avoid clutter
- Unicode and 2d rendering of mathematical functions
- Designed for parallel execution (for each defaults to it)
- Strong support for custom libraries (Guy Steele's influence)
- Operator overloading, including the juxtaposition operator

More info at the [Project Fortress Community website](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community/) and the [Wikipedia Fortress page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(programming_language)).

Comment: @RoelSpilker: Wasn't me. Went to the site, couldn't download the spec.   Being a Fortran descendant doesn't seem to fit the bill as a functional language? Am I wrong?

Comment: Although at first glance it look as just a new version of Fortran, it is also influenced by Scala and Haskell. And the way the language is designed, it supports both Objects and Traits. See the FAQ as well: http://research.sun.com/projects/plrg/faq/index.html#five

Comment: @RoelSpiker: +1 ...  Sounds good but I'm wondering as to the General momentum behind it.  Their "roadmap" doesn't lead anywhere currently.  :s

Comment: interesting, but probably going to fail! I'll vote up though!

Comment: Sun made the project open source just after they didn't get a renewal from DARPA, even though they had a running prototype/proof of concept. Since then, a lot of people got involved and helping improving Fortress. But I couldn't find who leads the project.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably none because the JVM lacks tail calls and they are required to make almost all functional code robust with respect to stack consumption.

The nearest thing to functional language implementations on the JVM are [Clojure](http://clojure.org/), [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and the [OCaml-Java](http://ocamljava.x9c.fr/) project. Although there are workarounds for the lack of tail calls (e.g. trampolining), none of these language implementations do this because the workarounds introduce even more serious problems, e.g. crippling performance and completely obfuscating debugging.

Sun have been talking about tail calls for years and, more recently, have indicated that they intend to implement them imminently. As soon as that is done, I am sure we will see a lot more language diversity on the JVM and, in particular, some production-quality functional language implementations. Until then, I regard all of these languages as toys.

Cheers,
Jon Harrop.

Comment: Once again John Harrop tells us fairy tales about how "tail calls are *required*" (emphasis mine) for functional code. Whoever reads that - it's simply not true. Granted, tail call support is nice to have - just like a FPU is nice to have, but not *required* to do floating point computations.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good list of programming languages for JVM, including functional programming paradigm and other paradigm languages on:

- en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages

My first pick is Scala (multi-paradigm; OO & FP), I spent a 5+ months studing Scala in 2009, and created a quick reference sheet: bchiprog.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-cheat-sheet.html

I noticed there are other programming paradigms that are interesting, other focuses on parallel processing such as X10, Fortress, and Chapel. X10 is implemented on top of Scala - http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/odersky/scalaliftoff2009.pdf

It's really based on what problem you need to solve then pick the language that can best solve it. I think it's developers' wish that there's one language that can solve any type of problem easily and doing it simply.

Answer (score 1):

@Marc Gravell - functional languages are increasingly used in the guts of enterprise grade financial systems. We use many functional (pure or "semi-pure") at the bank I work for...

Comment: That doesn't change anything... I said "as mainstream as the other .NET languages", and I'll stand by that. I expect there to be more non-FP code than FP code in most business systems for a considerable time.

Comment: This should probably have been a comment, not a post, btw.

Comment: @Marc: I'm not sure what either of your predictions mean. Is IronPython a mainstream .NET language? Isn't most F# code non-FP in practice? I think FP is often a red herring in the context of F#. People latch onto FP because they hear the Haskell hype but it is not very important in practice. The practical benefits of F# lie elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, there is [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege), a pure functional, non-strict language in the spirit of Haskell that compiles to Java, which then is compiled further with javac or the eclipse compiler, depending on the environment (command-line or eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I might be wrong, but I don't expect F# to be as mainstream as the other .NET languages; useful in a few circles (academic, compilers, a few other scenarios) - however, don't forget that **C#** offers FP usage - and it gets better each time: C# 1.2 has delegates; C# 2.0 has anonymous methods and captures/closures; C# 3.0 has lambdas for simplicity, and Expression for abstraction. Anonymous types (C# 3.0) share *some* similarity with tuples (in terms of convenience), but obviously are very different beasts,  so definitely not a like-for-like comparison.

Maybe not quite as optimised as F#, but for most day-to-day FP use-cases, more than sufficient.

It is also quite clear that better support for immutability (especially for threading) is very much on the minds of the C# language team for future consideration.

My money is on C# getting better at FP, and being the .NET FP offering for most day-to-day purposes. Of course, there will be some F# usage - but (purely subjective) I simply don't see there being a huge migration.

Comment: Does not answer the question. Even if F# remains irrelevant, the question could be asking for the equivalent irrelevant FP language for the JVM.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: we've had this conversation before ;-p But yes, absolutely: for the most part, I fully expect people to stay with C#. There is a niche where F# may be desirable, but I personally do not imagine any huge migration. Care to counter with something more concrete than just a "-1"?

Comment: Downvoters; please give me an indication **what** you disagree with? I'd love to know... is it disgruntled F# fans? Fine: then rather than just downvoting, tell me *why* you think F# is going to have an effect on the *general* .NET community. I agree is has uses in *very specific* scenarios, but for most general line-of-business code it simply isn't the most appropriate tool. If it is people angry I didn't answer the question (i.e. FP for the JVM): IMO, the *premise* of the question is wrong, and I stand by that...

Comment: The question is: "What Functional Programming languages are available, or in development, for the JVM?".

Your answer was a F# vs C# argument. You are answering the wrong question.

Comment: No, the question was "...which does for the Java Community what F# does for the .NET Community." - my answer merely attempts to put a perspective on this  - otherwise, the question is meaningless.

Comment: @Marc: "Care to counter with something more concrete than just a -1". Sure, millions of developers now have F# at their fingertips in VS2010 and it has clear benefits like pattern matching over variant types for manipulating trees, type inference giving the productivity of a dynamic language with the speed of C#, `MailboxProcessor` to make concurrent programming easy and async IO support to handle tens of thousands of simultaneous connections seamlessly. They aren't going to wait years for similar features to be retrofitted onto C# when they can solve their problems easily today using F#.

Comment: @Jon we've had fully asynchronous IO in .NET since day zero. This might not sound kind, but anyone who can't "grok" the original callback-based API *probably* shouldn't  be trying to write async code ***anyway***: making it *easier to type* (via F#, or the C# 5 stuff) doesn't really take away any of the subtle complications of async code. Also, while I realise you're an advocate (fair enough), having it at their fingertips isn't the same as them using it. In fact, just this week I have been...

Comment: @Jon writing some async-intensive code (pipelined, multiplexed, IOCP-centric, queued, callbacks, etc; all those nice things). In exactly ***zero ways*** did I find regular .NET lacking. As it happens I used C#, but any .NET language would have worked.

Comment: @Jon and re those other "benefits" - again, this is a great answer to a problem that I ***do not have***, and most other devs I know do not have. I fully accept that in a particular niche (or niches) this is highly useful; but most people don't need that, so why would they want to "solve" this problem (that they don't have) by switching to F#?

Comment: @Marc: I do not agree that programmers should be able to write low-level async code by hand before using high-level alternatives. No more than they should be able to do TCO on assembler by hand, or implement a write barrier before they use a GC. If this style of async is so bad, why did F# take it from OCaml and why is C# now taking it from F#?

Comment: @Jon and yet we got by just fine... And focusing on async is probably not a great argument here anyway precisely **because** of the c# async CTP - i.e. if this is coming (available now with production license) to c#, why would I need to consider f# for async?

Comment: @Marc: "yet we got by just fine". People say that every time programming languages evolve.

Comment: @Marc: "why would I need to consider f# for async?" Why would I need to stay ahead of the curve?

Comment: @Jon - it is merely a convenience syntax... and in some ways *less* so than similar things like "iterator blocks"; yet again, my point: this isn't a problem that is causing daily pain, even when writing highly async code. It is definitely nice to have, and I welcome it (I have already developed some C# 5-style async libraries, etc). But: I also wrote the exact same code *without* the async CTP. The conversion was absolutely minimal. The strength of the async / F# argument is hugely disproportionate to real, every-day async coding, which is alive and well without F# or C# 5.

Comment: @Marc: "which is alive and well without F# or C# 5". Sure, you can do async in C++ or Fortran or assembler too. If that is too far afield, look at the way C# developers treated .NET generics when they landed (assuming you use generics): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/03/15/net-c-generics-history-some-photos-from-feb-1999.aspx

Comment: @Jon - you continue to skate around the point: the fact is, with or without the async CTP, for the vast majority of C# developers writing async code is not a significant problem that needs a language swap to fix. Making it prettier with language support is *welcome* of course.

Comment: @Marc: You don't have to swap languages on .NET. Just choose the right one for the task.

Comment: @Jon I routinely do :) however, I strongly suspect we might make different decisions on that (ultimately subjective) design question.

Answer (score 0):

I would add https://eta-lang.org to the suggestions -- it's basically a Haskell for the JVM. I think the question is in line with the fact that F# is an ML language, while Clojure is a dialect of LISP.